# I can't mock property of class

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, spock

I've just started using spock and I am facing one issue..

```
    public class UserAuthentication {
        private UserDAO userDao;

        public boolean authenticateUser(String email, String password){
            User user = userDao.findUserByEmail(email);

            if(password.equals(user.getDecodedPassword())){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
}


public interface UserDAO {

    User findUserByEmail(String login);

    void saveUser(User user);
}

public class User {

    private String email;
    private String decodedPassword;

    public User(String email, String decodedPassword) {
        this.email = email;
        this.decodedPassword = decodedPassword;
    }(...)
```

Unfortunately my test throw NullPointerException:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import spock.lang.Specification

class UserAuthenticationTest extends Specification {

    def "Authenticating correct user" () {
        setup:
        def email = "email@email.com"
        def password = "qwerty1234"

        def userDao = Mock(UserDAO)
        userDao.findUserByEmail(email) >> new User(email, password)

        def userAuthenticator = new UserAuthentication()
        userAuthenticator.setUserDao(userDao)

        when:
        def result = userAuthenticator.authenticateUser(email, password)

        then:
        1 * userDao.findUserByEmail(email)
        result == true
    }

}
```

[image]

I got the exception because mock doesn't work when is invoked (userDao.findUserByEmail(email); in UserAuthentication class).

Anyone have some idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you both mock and verify the returned (from mock) expression should be placed under `then` block. [Here](http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/interaction_based_testing.html#combining-mocking-and-stubbing) are the docs and below You can find corrected code:

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0')
@Grab('cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1')

import spock.lang.*
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

class UserAuthenticationTest extends Specification {

    def "Authenticating correct user" () {
        setup:
        def email = "email@email.com"
        def password = "qwerty1234"

        def userDao = Mock(UserDAO) 

        def userAuthenticator = new UserAuthentication()
        userAuthenticator.userDao = userDao

        when:
        def result = userAuthenticator.authenticateUser(email, password)

        then:
        1 * userDao.findUserByEmail(email) >>  new User(email, password)
        result == true
    }
}

public class UserAuthentication {
    UserDAO userDao;

    public boolean authenticateUser(String email, String password){
        User user = userDao.findUserByEmail(email);        
        return password.equals(user.getDecodedPassword());
    }
}

public interface UserDAO {

    User findUserByEmail(String login);

    void saveUser(User user);
}

public class User {

    private String email;
    private String decodedPassword;

    public User(String email, String decodedPassword) {
        this.email = email;
        this.decodedPassword = decodedPassword;
    }

    public String getDecodedPassword() {
        return decodedPassword;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank! It solved my problem but could you explain me why it works that way?

Comment: See here: http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/interaction_based_testing.html#combining-mocking-and-stubbing

Comment: Broken link: now see http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1-rc-3/all_in_one.html & search "combining mocking and stubbing"